# Architecture for MarkLogic cluster

Tags: marklogic

My current DB size is approx **1.7 TB**

I am working on redesigning the MarkLogic cluster.

I am able to draw this cluster configuration.

[image]

In the image columns in grey are primary forests and the blue one are replicas (`*-R-*`).

Note: MODULES to BATCH database won't have much data in it.

Is there any modification required for the cluster? or this is good to go with?

Comment: Is that 1.7 Tb in just your primary forests, or does that include all the replicas?

Comment: Primary forests only

Answer (score 3):

In your architecture, more than 2 replicas is likely not going to be very useful.  You have 5 hosts, so you can lose up 2.   Once you lose a 3rd host, your cluster won't have [enough hosts for a quorum](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/clustering#id_36521), and will be unavailable.  It's also important to note that each replica will also increase the load on the host and the amount of intra-cluster coordination traffic.

You do have the content forest replicas striped across the cluster hosts, which is the recommended method.  Striping is recommended to ensure that any 1 host failure won't overload another host, but in this case, all the load from one host will move over to one other host.  With 5 primary forests spread across 5 hosts, each host is managing 20% of the load.  If any one host fails, the load on the host with the replica will go to 40%, while the rest will stay at 20%.  This effect can be mitigated by increasing the number of primary forests on each host.

For example, with 10 primary forests spread across 5 hosts, and replicas striped across those hosts, when a host fails 2 hosts will each managed 30% of the load, while the other two hosts stay at 20% each.  In your case, the downside of this setup is that to have HA, each host will need 4 content forests (2 primary & 2 replica), where currently you only need 3 content forests per host (1 primary & 2 replica).

Also, with 1.7 Tb in your primary content forests, that works out to around 348 GB per forest.  Query response times may also be able to be reduced by increasing the number of primary forests.  With 10 forests, you would end up with around 174 Gb per primary forest.  Assuming you [have the cpu threads and memory available](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/scalability#id_96443) to support the extra forests, then this could improve response times.

So to summarize, reduce the number of replica forests to no more than 2. Test whether hosts can support a doubled workload in the event of a failure, and if they can't, mitigate the risk by increasing the number of primary content forests.

As for the other databases, I would take the two smallest (or least used) databases and host their forests on 1 host.  The rest I would stripe across the cluster.  For example, if Schema & Modules are the smallest, here is a possible lay out.

```
Host 1  -  Host 2  -  Host 3  -  Host 4  -  Host 5
========   ========   ========   ========   ========
Mod-1      Mod-R-1    Mod-R-2
Trgr-1     Trgr-R-1   Trgr-R-2
           Sch-1      Sch-R-1    Sch-R-2
                      Enttl-1    Enttl-R-1   Enttl-R-2
Audit-R-2                        Audit-1     Audit-R-1
Batch-R-1  Batch-R-2                         Batch-1
```

Comment: Thank Michael for the detailed answer. Helps a lot. Please also give your views on the other dbs (other than content), is the replicas created are right? (Audit db is of 22GB size and others are of approx 200-300 MBs in size)

Comment: @DixitSingla  I've updated the answer with additional suggestions

Comment: The layout looks really good. Is it possible to achieve the same layout by ml gradle property references?

Comment: @DixitSingla I believe so, but I haven't done it myself.

Comment: Thanks you, I will play around it. Thanks again.